# Java - Do java have something like C#'s struct automatic constructor

Tags: c#, java, constructor

I've been using C# for a long time and now I need to do something in Java.

Is there something like C#'s struct automatic constructor in java ?

What I mean is
In C#

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int i;
}
class Program
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        MyStruct mStruct; // Automatic constructor was invoked; This line is same as MyStruct mStruct = new MyStruct();
        mStruct.i = 5;   // mStruct is not null and can i can be assigned
    }
}
```

Is it possible to force java to use default constructor on declaration ?

Comment: what's the problem with calling that constructor explicitly?

Comment: C# doesn't automatically invoke the default constructor on structs.

Comment: "Automatic constructor was invoked" is *not* what happens at all. C# *also* doesn't have this "automatic constructor".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - Java doesn't support custom value types at all, and constructors are always explicitly called.

However, your understanding of C# is incorrect anyway. From your original post:

```
// Automatic constructor was invoked
// This line is same as MyStruct mStruct = new MyStruct();
MyStruct mStruct;
```

That's not true. You can *write* to `mStruct.i` without any explicit initialization here, but you can't *read* from it unless the compiler knows everything has been assigned a value:

```
MyStruct x1; 
Console.WriteLine(x1.i); // Error: CS0170: Use of possibly unassigned field 'i'

MyStruct x1 = new MyStruct();
Console.WriteLine(x1.i); // No error
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you always need to explicitly call a constructor in Java.

Since there may be multiple constructors, calling a specific constructor explicitly would probably be good practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support the Struct keyword (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228600(v=VS.90).aspx) so you would be needing to use a Class with only public objects (and no functions.) You always need to initialise classes.