# How to write Class in Android Java that give me return more then one object ? (like in C# I can do same with struct)

Tags: java, android

I want to reurn my custom object in Java. How I can do. From looking to people's answer it's look like Java don't support custom object.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11701816/713789

```
public class FinanceManager {

    public String Compname;

    public FinanceManager(String Compname){
        this.Compname = Compname;
    }

    public static CustomValueReturn(){
        return ;;
        // I need to return a custom object which return too many object as single object.
    }

}
```

Someone please help me how I can do it in java. I have tried .net very few and in .net I make struct and return a struct who have a lot of detail so function can return bunch of detail instead of Single string or object.

Comment: java supports custom object (its just an instance of a class) but do not support custom value type ie datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. Create a model class for your return. For instance, say you want to return `CustomObject`.

```
class CustomObject {
    private blabla ..;
    /getters setters and what not

}
```

Now in your "returning method"

```
public class FinanceManager {
    private CustomObject instanceOfCustomObject;
    public String Compname;

    public FinanceManager(String Compname){
        this.Compname = Compname;
        this.instanceOfCustomObject = new CustomObject();
    }

    public CustomObject getInstanceOfCustomObject(){
        return this.instanceOfCustomObject
        // I need to return a custom object which return too many object as single object.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
public static class MyCompound {
   public final String a;
   public final String b;
   public MyCompund(String a,String b) {
     this.a=a;
     this.b=b;
   }
}

public MyCompound testCompundReturn(String input) {
   return new MyCompound(input,"hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a container, `Map`, `List` or an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a custom object just create a class for your custom object and return an instance of that class:

```
class mycustomobject {
  int int1;
  String string1;
  //and so on...

}
```

For more information see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) tutorial

If you want to return multiple objects use a container or an array.